# Python Requests Decoding Error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to scrape JSON data from API and I am getting decoding errors. Any know what could be wrong?

```
r = requests.session()
    headers = {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
        "Accept-Language": "cs-CZ,cs;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.6 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
    }

    getPage = r.get("https://www.footshop.cz/cs/api/product/308110", headers=headers)

    x = json.loads(getPage.text)
    print(x)
```

I did this many times on different web sites and didn't have any issues. I am only getting this error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tried to Google but can't really find anything that works for me.

Comment: `getPage.text` is `''` (an empty string).  The request isn't returning anything.  Try a little debugging like `print(getPage.text)` first.

Comment: FYI: If the request *did* return JSON, `x = getPage.json()` would be more direct than `x = json.loads(getPage.text)`.

Comment: I tried `print(getPage.text)` as well but it is waiting for like a few seconds and then ends. Doesnt print anything

Comment: It doesn't print anything because it returns an empty string.  The long wait is how long the request is taking.  It returns 200 (success) so whatever request you are trying to make is incorrect.  Use `print(repr(getPage.text))` to see the empty quotes.